# WinBSOD after GRUB2

Tags: windows, bsod, grub, linux

Доброго времени суток, я хотел бы собрать конструктивные мнения, ибо моя голова и гугление уже не может мне помочь. Не вдаваясь в волокиту предистории, хотя там очень много забавных моментов, скажу такую весч - > из под линукса пропал wifi, я пытался его поднять, оживить - итог оживил, но в результате , каких то неведомых мне действий, а может ведомых, - потому что  в сердцах я решил снести его, но потом передумал и отменил  установку, грубым правда образом, выключив комп, ну просто он не реагировал на мня собака, -  винда после того как GRUB2 отобразил свое меню грузится , грузится, грузится, а потом говорить BSOD тебе, да так быстро, что я даже взглянуть не успеваю, что там такое, перегружаемся, опять грузим Окошко, а оно говорит, Восстанови систему Юзер, я ей, давай, она мне через минут сорок говорит, я не могу; я иду в Лин, смотрю, виндовые разделы целы, все нормально, я по ним брожу, гуляю, сейчас вот бэки делаю, на пожарный, так вот понять не могу, чего не нравится винде??? , что она так истерит и не грузится.....может устройство отпадает и оно кричит караул???? менять не выход. там работа текущая у меня, ))) очень много сопутствующего ПО)) а это увы не единый репозиторий)))) ну и лень мне там всю гадость делать)по установке )Засим обращаюсь к вам))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Нажимаем F8, выбираем "Отключить автоперезагрузку" и читаем на Экране Смерти;

2) Ставите установочный диск Окошек, затем нажимаем ентер, затем Установить, затем смотрим. Если программа установки говорит, что осталась старая система -- отлично, жмем R, т.е. пытаемся восстановить.

3) Используя ERD Commander (если Окошки версии XP), загружаемся, смотрим все логи, реестр, откат системы.

4) А что, в Окошках безопасный режим ничего не дает?

5) Есть у меня такая штука, называется [FreeXPIE](http://freexpie.ru/), очень полезная штука при работе с диском. Можете действие испытать на своем компе.

6 и т.д.) Только после 1)

Comment: Я ваш ответ засчитаю) для приличия , но оказалось, что все по другому )) это все асус , он выставляет интересные заводские настройки биоса для видеокарты и жесктого диска , при этом великий Линус сделал все ок, линукс работает и при таких настройках, а вот ребята из Майкрософт сказали по другому))) спасибо , ваш ответ наверное кому то пригодиться в будущем))

Comment: @rojaster, спасибо))